# ¿Como modifico las variables capacity y free que la informacion que me saque este en gigas?

Tags: python, variables

¿Como puedo modificar las variables capacity y free para que represente la información devuelta en formato de gigasbytes?

Obtener información del espacio en disco

```
try:
    disks = connection.Win32_LogicalDisk(DriveType=3)  # Solo discos locales

    # Imprimir la información de espacio en disco
    print(f"Información de espacio en disco en el host: {hostname}")
    print("----------------------------------------------------")

    for disk in disks:
        name = disk.DeviceID
        capacity = disk.Size
        free = disk.FreeSpace
        root = disk.Caption

        print(f"Disco: {name} - Punto de montaje: {root}")
        print(f"Capacidad: {capacity} bytes")
        print(f"Libre: {free} bytes")
        print("--------------------------------------")

except Exception as ex:
    print(f"Error en el host: {hostname}")
    print(str(ex))
```

Comment: Convirtiendo `bytes` a `gigas`. Supongo que sabes dividir en Python. Entonces no es más que una división. Pista: no es entre multiplos de `1000` que has de dividir, recuerda que 1Kb no es 1000 bytes sino 1024 bytes. ;)

Comment: Podrías agregar algún enlace de referencia a la documentación para `Win32_LogicalDisk`?. Hasta ahora he conseguido un [repositorio de github](https://github.com/mhammond/pywin32) pero no puedo hallar ese modulo.

Answer (score 1):

Debes de dividir los bytes retornados por `disk.Size` y `disk.FreeSpace` por `1073741824`.

Si usas `%` para darle formato a un numero flotante entonces reducirá la cantidad de decimales:

```
>>> "%f" % (3123123123 / 1073741824)
'2.908635'
```

diferencia de `str.format`

```
>>> "{}".format(3123123123 / 1073741824)
'2.908635067753494'
```

```
print("Disco: %s - Punto de montaje: %s" % (name, root))
print("Capacidad: %f bytes" % (capacity / 1073741824))
print(f"Libre: %f bytes" % (free / 1073741824))
print("--------------------------------------")
```

Esto lo saque de este [foro de preguntas](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1194517).

Comment: También se puede especificar la cantidad de decimales, por ejemplo en los f-string: `print(f"Capacidad: {capacity/1073741824:.2f} GB")` Salida de prueba:  `... 320.18 GB`

Comment: Okay, usar un valor predeterminado es una opción favorable, pero podrían tener un tamaño predeterminado en gigasbytes?, pensé en colocar eso como respuesta, pero me parece muy muy incierto, entonces solo dejo que el usuario decida si usar una valor predeterminado + la cantidad (flotante?) o usar una especie dedicada de formato.